# Tamaño excesivo url

Tags: php, apache, servidor

Tengo un GET con unas 400 variables que genera una url de unos 9000 caracteres.
El caso es que me lanza el siguiente error:

---

414 Request-URI Too Large

## Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.

---

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.1.6.44 Port 80

He modificado en php.ini las variables post_max_size,upload_max_filesize, output_buffering, max_input_vars dejandolas en 32Mg y 1000 variables.

Por que mas se puede dar este error?
Lo curioso es que con 8000 caracteres si que funciona,la diferencia es que quito las variables vacías, pero si hago un get con solo una variable y esta está vacía, también funciona.

este es el código con el que genero la url desde javascript

```js
var url = "/configuracion.php?";
for (var param in prod){
      url += param + '=' + Window.[param] + '&';
}
url=url.substr(0, url.length-1);
$.get(url);
```

Comment: En vez de get mándalas por post

Comment: por post me da el mismo error

Comment: Lo que tienes es un error de diseño.

Comment: Que error puede ser?

Comment: No se me ocurre ni un solo caso de uso en el que una petición de una URL tenga que tener 9000 variables. Deberías rediseñar tu script. Por qué necesitas tantas? Podrías guardar esta información en una base de datos o fichero y mandar por la url únicamente el id del registro o nombre del archivo.

Comment: Divide y vencerás. Secciona los formularios en grupos de opciones independientes. Entiendo que lo que trabajas es un panel de configuración de algo (por lo del `var url = 'configuracion.php?';`) Ej: Configuración de URL, configuración del sistema etc etc

Comment: ¿Si lo mandas por Ajax te da error?

Comment: @Muriano Son 400 variables con 8000 caracteres... pero siguen siendo demasiadas, sobre todo para una consulta (si usa GET asumo que no lo usa para guardar datos). claramente tiene que repensarse algo

Comment: @Muriano Totalmente deacuerdo con tigo y el resto de compañeros, esto sinceramente aparente un error de diseño. En caso de que fuese un form tan grande lo mas optimo seria dividir como apunta Cedano, o actualizar cada input de forma independiente con ajax solo cuando existan cambios

Comment: @ jonilgz  Efectivamente es un panel de control de un motor paso a paso con sensores, lo que hace configuracion.php es crear unos mensajes específicos para mandar al control del motor por socket, y necesita todas las variables.  Lo he solucionado dividiendo de 100 en 100 variables.   Aun así, no me explico por que me daba el error, si html no limita, php y apache los tengo sobredimensionados a 32Mg y estoy utilizando  firefox   | 65536.

Comment: ¿Probaste con Ajax? Solamente por la curiosidad que planteas sobre por qué no funciona...

Comment: $.get(url) es una funcion de jquery que equivale a:            $.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

Comment: [En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17810063/5587982) se resolvió el envío de un formulario de 3MB mediante una petición ajax clásica. No descartes intentarlo así, serializando tu formulario y pasándolo en el `data`. ¿O tú formulario tiene más de 3MB?

Comment: Me uno, no deberías de tener problemas mandando todo en un post (usando el body, no la url para pasar los parámetros), aunque para que todo sea más fluido separar en varios request también es una gran opción.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error `414 Request-URI Too Large` que te retona el servidor es debido a que la URI es considerada demasiado larga por el servidor, esto viene descrito en la [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1), el protocolo http por defecto no establece un limite para las URI's, este limite viene dado por el servidor, el lenguaje y por el cliente (el navegador en este caso), y suele estar establecido en valores medios para evitar denegacion de servicio principalmente

En **PHP** entran en juego las siguiente directivas para limitar los limites de las URI's:

[max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) por defecto 1000

[max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) por defecto 60

[max_input_nesting_level](http://php.net/manual/es/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level) por defecto 64

[post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) por defecto 8M

En **apache** en contramos las siguientes directivas:

[LimitRequestLine](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) 8190 bytes

[LimitRequestFieldSize](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize) 8190 bytes

En cuanto a los **navegadores** echando un vistazo rápido encontramos lo siguiente:

```
Navegador  | Caracteres**
-----------+------------
 IE        | 2048
 Chrome    | 64000
 firefox   | 65536
 Safari    | 80000
 Opera     | 190000
```

***El numero de caracteres admitido por cada navegado puede ser diferente en función de las versiones y del sistema operativo. En la gran mayoría de versiones antiguas de los navegadores el limite es 2048 Caracteres.*

Para mi realmente tienes un error de concepto, se me ocurren muy pocos casos en los que se requieran más de 500 caracteres en la URI y aun menos en los que sea necesario enviar 400 variables, deberías plantearte si estas tomando el camino correcto antes de avanzar en este sentido.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:  Request-URI Too Large The requested URL's length exceeds the
>   capacity limit for this server.

Solución:
Se modifica el archivo de configuración de apache ubicado en:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
```

se agregregan las lineas al final:

```
LimitRequestLine 10000
LimitRequestFieldSize 10000
```

Se reinicia el servicio de apache

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Revisa recargando la pagina, debió solucionarse el problema.