# Se puede parsear HTML de gran tamaño?

Tags: php, html

necesito parsear archivos HTML grandes, estos pesan mas de 50 MB, y hay algunos que de estos archivos que los tengo pasados por un Beutifer (http://jsbeautifier.org/) y llegan a tener mas de 600.000 lineas.

Yo solo hice una prueba para probar solo si era posible con un archivo chico y si se puede, pero con los archivos grandes de mas de me da un error.
Probe cambiando el php.ini:
upload_max_filesize = 60M
post_max_size = 60M

pero tampoco funciona, acá pongo el código que use en local usando wamserver:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">  
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="40" cols="100"></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Aclaro que con este código SOLO quería probar si al ser archivos de gran tamaño el navegador lo soportaba, lo que quiero hacer es tomar ese codigo con PHP y parsearlo con DOMdocument, o antes parsearlo con Jquery y pararlo  a PHP solo para que guarde partes de este codigo en una base de datos.

Mi duda es solo si es posible o NO trabajar desde un Texarea con tanta cantidad de datos, quizas deba hacerlo de otra manera.

GRACIAS desde ya.

Comment: Un `TextArea` no tiene límites, puedes introducir en él todos los megas que quieras, y miles y millones de caracteres. La cuestión aquí es otra: **debes hacerlo de otra manera**. Por muchísimos motivos, entre ellos: que el servidor posiblemente no dará la talla, y si la da, entonces posiblemente  los navegadores de muchos clientes se quedarán bloqueados descargando tal cantidad de contenido, y si lo descargan, desplazarse por esa `TextArea` será algo que requerirá de mucha paciencia, si es que alguien se anima a leer todo eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano es verdad que el textarea como tal no tiene límite,  más bien el límite viene dado por los navegadores y por el propio servidor, y claro está que caracteres por valor 50mb. En esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130034/tama%c3%b1o-excesivo-url/130045#130045 deje algunos de los límites más comunes, muchos de ellos afectan también a post no solo a la uri como se planteó en esa pregunta

Comment: Y como puedo hacerlo? lo que quiero hacer es de alguna manera poder parsear estos archivos HTML de gran tamaño para dividirlo por partes en bases de datos y así acceder por querys SQL solo a los datos que necesito en determinado momento.   Lo del texarea lo hice por una cuestión de que quería hacer algo simple donde pegar código y que desde ahí pueda parsearse, pero creo que debo usar otro método. Como dije antes el servidor que tengo es Apache en Wampserver y solo usare estos datos en local.  Quizas deba cambiar configuraciones tambien de Apache o del navegador GC.