# Enviar Array de Bytes. Error 414, Request URI Too Long

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, array, api

Estoy tratando de insertar un Array de bytes por API.

La llamada la realizamos desde una Web (Angularjs + PHP)

La API que la recibe esta desarrollada en .NET

El problema con el que me encuentro es el siguiente. Lanzamos una petición GET hacia una URL, junto con un JSON Como parámetro.

```
$urlInsercionDocumento = "1.1.1.1/Documento/InsertDatosDocumentoBytes/?Facturacion_ContratosDocumentosAPIDTO={'IdEmpresa':'1','IdUsuario':'1','ContratosDocumento':[{'IdCliente':'1','CodigoContrato':'1','Nombre':'Nombre','IdUsuarioCreador':'1','IsBloqueado':false,'IdDocumento':'','FileName':'NombreFichero','FileSize':'1111','FechaCreacion':'2018-01-01','FechaModificacion':'','Fichero':'Array de bytes codificado en base64'}]}";
```

Esta es la URL desde la que lanzo la petición.

El ***problema*** surge cuando al llegar al servidor me lanza un ***error 414, URI demasiado larga.***

Entiendo que es porque no es el procedimiento correcto, el enviar este documento, codificado como un array de bytes en base64.

No se si debería pasarlo en el body, o donde. ¿Algún consejo?

Tras cambiarlo a POST, veo el siguiente mensaje:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Request URL Too Long</TITLE>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h2>Request URL Too Long</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.</p>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Pues es simple, tu problema radica en que tu peticion es de tipo `GET`, cambialo a `POST` que es lo mas indicado para enviar este tipo de dato.

Comment: Lo he cambiado a POST y sigue sin funcionar. Da error 414.

Comment: @Diego, además de cambiarlo a POST lo estas enviando en el cuerpo de la peticion en lugar de la url?? Eso debería funcionar.

Comment: @Diego, si aun cambiando a `POST`, no funciona podrias cambia el tamaño de `LimitRequestLine` en el archivo /etc/apache2/apache2.conf , poco recomendable pero silo necesitas ahi estaria la solucion

Comment: @Diego, Otra solucion seria enviar la informacion por **tramos**, es decir dividir la informacion en **N** partes y enviar **N+1** respuestas, y concatenarlas / volver a unirlas una ves que tengas toda la informacion, que es lo que muchos hacen, o simplemente utilizar un algoritmo de compresión que seria una buena opcion, el problema en el ultimo seria estar seguro de la integridad de los datos. **como no muestras nada de codigo reproducible** no es posible ayudarte mas, informas como te fue vale.

Comment: La primera no me convence, es enviar un PDF, no creo que sea necesario. Respecto al tema de la compresión, podrías decirme que tipo de compresión?

Comment: Esto quizas te arroje un poco de luz: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130045/38103

Comment: Al ver el error `HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.` lo que parece es que cambiaste el método pero no la url... Me explico: no solo debes cambiar GET por POST,sino que además debes enviar el array en el cuerpo de la petición, para que la url sea solo `1.1.1.1/Documento/InsertDatosDocumentoBytes/` este es un ejemplo con jquery: `$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'1.1.1.1/Documento/InsertDatosDocumentoBytes/',data:myArray}).done(callback(data))`;