# Paso de valores por post de un input via javascript a php no funciona al cambiar de hosting

Tags: php, javascript, post

El input del formulario es:

```
         <form name="afegir" action="funcion_quimics.php" method="post" onSubmit="return valida_afegir(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset=utf-8 >             
        <br><br>
        <?
        $descripciones=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tiposenvase");
        $descripciones = $descripciones->fetch_array();

        while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()){
            ?>
            <fieldset style=" border-radius:5px; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px;">
            <?
            $fila_aux = str_replace(".","_",$fila['idRes']);
            echo "<div> ".$fila['idRes']."<h4 style='vertical-align:middle; margin-left:5px; display:inline'> - ".$fila['denominacion'].".<img id='im".$fila_aux."' src='plus.png' style='cursor:pointer; padding-left:10px; vertical-align:bottom; height:24px; width:24px;' onclick=\"showdiv('".$fila_aux."')\" /></h4> </div><br>
        <div id='".$fila_aux."' style='display:none'>";
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //Gestion de los campos de envases//
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $NoRetorn = '';
        $Retorn = '';
        switch ($fila['tipus']) {
            case '1'://Només té no retornables
                $Retorn = 'disabled';
                break;
            case '2'://Només té retornables
                $NoRetorn = 'disabled';
                break;
        }
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="border_right">Descripció i detall del residu(2)</td>
        <?
            $finfo = $resultado->fetch_fields();
            for ($i=3; $i < count($finfo); $i++) { 
                $aux=$finfo[$i]->name;
                if ($fila[$aux]==1){
                    echo "<td class='border_right'>".$descripciones[$aux]."</td>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <?
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='info_".$fila_aux."' value=''></td>";
            //echo "<input type='hidden' name='llista[]' value='".$fila_aux."'>";
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283755/disable-submit-functionality-for-all-forms-on-a-html-page
            for ($i=3; $i < count($finfo); $i++) { 
                $aux=$finfo[$i]->name;
                if (($aux=='ENV1L') || ($aux=='ENV2L')){
                    $disabled = "disabled title='Aquest envàs no pot ser retornable'";
                } else {
                    $disabled = '';
                }
                $rest = substr($aux, 3);
                if ($fila[$aux]==1){
                    echo "<td><table><tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' id='n".$rest."_".$fila_aux."' name='n".$rest."_".$fila_aux."' value='' size='3' $NoRetorn ></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' id='r".$rest."_".$fila_aux."' name='r".$rest."_".$fila_aux."' value='' size='3' style='background-color:#CEFFE9' $disabled $Retorn ></td>";
                    echo "</tr></table></td>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <?
        echo "</div>";
        ?> </fieldset> <?
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <center><img src="../images/separador_440px.gif" alt="" width="434px" height="1px"></center>
        <br>
        <?
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///NUEVOS RESIDUOS CON EXCEL INDEPENDIENTE///
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        $consulta_2 = "SELECT * FROM descripciones2";
        $resultado_nuevos=$conexion->query($consulta_2);

        while($fila = $resultado_nuevos->fetch_array()){
            ?>
            <fieldset style=" border-radius:5px; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px;">
            <?
            $fila_diferentes = str_replace(".","_",$fila['idRes']);
            echo "<div> ".$fila['idRes']."<h4 style='vertical-align:middle; margin-left:5px; display:inline'> - ".$fila['denominacion'].".<img id='im".$fila_aux."' src='plus.png' style='cursor:pointer; padding-left:10px; vertical-align:bottom; height:24px; width:24px;' onclick=\"showdiv('".$fila_diferentes."')\" /></h4> </div><br>
        <div id='".$fila_diferentes."' style='display:none'>";
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //Gestion de los campos de envases//
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="border_right">Descripció i detall del residu(2)</td>
        <?
            $finfo = $resultado_nuevos->fetch_fields();
            for ($i=2; $i < count($finfo); $i++) { 
                $aux=$finfo[$i]->name;
                if ($fila[$aux]==1){
                    echo "<td class='border_right'>".$descripciones[$aux]."</td>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <?
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='info_".$fila_diferentes."' value=''></td>";
            //echo "<input type='hidden' name='llista[]' value='".$fila_aux."'>";

            for ($i=2; $i < count($finfo); $i++) { 
                $aux=$finfo[$i]->name;
                $rest = substr($aux, 3);
                if ($fila[$aux]==1){
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type='text' id='new".$rest."_".$fila_diferentes."' name='new".$rest."_".$fila_diferentes."' value='' size='5'>";
                    echo "</td>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <?
        echo "</div>";
        ?> </fieldset> <?
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <div id="llista_id">
        </div>
        <?
        if ($result_hab['habilitat']==0){
        ?>
        <center><input type="submit" name="afegir_quimics" value="Acceptar" disabled="disabled"></center>
        <?
        } else {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert ("El búnquer es troba deshabilitat en aquests moments.");
        </script>
        <?
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        </form>
```

Array en javascript que pasaré a php:

```
var variables= new Array("r5LE_","r5LA_","r10LE_","r10LA_","r25LG_","r30LB_","r60LB_","r120LB_","rCPLASTICO_","r8LSEG_","r11LSEG_","rUnidades","rCFILTRE_","n1L_","n2L_","n5LE_","n5LA_","n10LE_","n10LA_","n25LG_","n30LB_","n60LB_","n120LB_","nCPLASTICO_","n8LSEG_","n11LSEG_","nUnidades_","nCFILTRE_","new60LN_","new30LN_","new10LN_","new5LN_","new3LN_","new2LN_","new1LN_");
```

Luego en un javascript

```
function valida_afegir(){
var mutli_education = document.afegir.elements["llista[]"];
var ele ='';
var trobat = false;
var trobat2 = false;
var x=0;
var i=0;

if (mutli_education.length>1){
    while ((x<mutli_education.length)/*&&(trobat==false)*/&&(trobat2==false)){
        i=0;
        while ((i<variables.length)/*&&(trobat==false)*/&&(trobat2==false)){
            ele=variables[i] + mutli_education[x].value;
            if (aux=document.getElementById(ele)){
                if (vacio(aux.value) == true){
                    trobat=true;

                }
                if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(aux.value)){
                    trobat2=true;   
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        x++;
    }
}else {
    i=0;
    while ((i<variables.length)/*&&(trobat==false)*/&&(trobat2==false)){
        ele=variables[i] + mutli_education.value;
        aux=document.getElementById(ele);
        if (aux=document.getElementById(ele)){
            if (vacio(aux.value) == true){
                trobat=true;        
            }
         if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(aux.value)){
            trobat2=true;   
            }
            }
        i++;
    }
}

if(trobat2==true){
    alert("El valor " + aux.value + " no es un nombre");
    return false;
        }
if (trobat==false){
    alert ("El formulari no pot estar en blanc.");
    return trobat;
}else {
    alert ("Tot correcte.");
    return true
}
```

}

Luego lo recojo así e inserto en la BBDD en otro php. Es un bucle con foreach porque pueden venir varios valores via post, varias peticiones de varios inputs, por eso el foreach para cada uno:

```
if ($_POST['llista_old']){
    foreach($_POST['llista_old'] as $check) {
        $info = addslashes($_POST["info_$check"]);
        $r5Le = $_POST['r5LE_$check'];
        $r5La = $_POST['r5LA_$check'];
        $r10Le = $_POST['r10LE_$check'];
        $r10La = $_POST['r10LA_$check'];
        $r25L = $_POST['r25LG_$check'];
        $r30L = $_POST['r30LB_$check'];
        $r60L = $_POST['r60LB_$check'];
        $r120L = $_POST['r120LB_$check'];
        $rcaixa = $_POST['rCPLASTICO_$check'];
        $rcaixa2 = $_POST['rCFILTRE_$check'];
        $r8L = $_POST['r8LSEG_$check'];
        $r11L = $_POST['r11LSEG_$check'];
        $unidades = $_POST['rUnidades_$check'];

       if(!($conexion->query("INSERT INTO retornables (idSol, idRes, 5LE, 5LA, 10LA, 10LE, 25LG, 30LB, 60LB, 120LB, CPLASTICO, 8LSEG, 11LSEG, Unidades, CFILTRE) VALUES (".$_SESSION['timest'].", '$aux', '$r5Le', '$r5La', '$r10La', '$r10Le', '$r25L', '$r30L', '$r60L', '$r120L', '$rcaixa', '$r8L', '$r11L', '$unidades', '$rcaixa2')"))){
                printf("La conexión con el servidor de base de datos falló: %s\n",  $conexion->error);exit(0);

        }
```

}

Pues esto **funciona** sin más en mi hosting actual, pero en el nuevo el post no recoge nada, está vacío en los `$_POST`. He probado temas de codificación (server por defecto en UTF-8) pero nada. En la consola del navegador no muestra nada relevante. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes poner el formulario entero, no sólo el input?

Comment: No se si sera esto pero  los envios por POST tienen un maximo de tamaño configurable a nivel de php. Echale un vistazo -> https://devanswers.co/php-apache-set-max-file-upload-post-size/

Comment: @Xerif Ya he añadido todo el form, pero creo que lo relevante es solo el input. Aparte hay muchas otras cosas.

Comment: @JDev Solo se pasan valores númericos, no se suben ficheros, por lo que no creo que vaya los tiros por el post_max_size

Comment: Cuando cambiaste el hosting, instalaste todo en las mismas carpetas?

Comment: @Juan Si, esta todo igual a nivel de ficheros y carpetas, y estamos en el proceso del cambio, no se ha cerrado el antiguo, estoy probando el nuevo entorno.

Comment: @Multimedia tambien hay un maximo para la longitud (no el tamaño) del POST

Comment: Seguramente tienes una versión diferente de php en el nuevo servidor (más nueva), cambia las etiquetas de apertura de php de <? a <?php

Comment: El atributo de accept-charset no está entre comillas. No se si es un error de tipeo.

Comment: En el inspector del navegador, en la parte de network, ves si viajan los valores al servidor?

Comment: @Juan Mirando en el inspector me pone enviado, 438b de tamaño. Creo que envia pero no recoge los valores por algún motivo que se me escapa

Comment: En esta respuesta puedes revisar el tamaño por defecto para las peticiones al servidor https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130045/38103 esto puede variar según tu hosting, revisa que no venga el error por ahí.  Revisa también el inspector de tu navegador para saber que te está respondiendo así como el Log por si hay algún error silenciado. También es interesante que nos indiques la versión de php, por que puede ser que si estás en una cesión reciente tu código no sea compatible. Como te comentaron el tag `<?` no debe utilizarse.

Comment: @Carmen acabo de cambiar las etiquetas, pero sigue sin recoger los $_POST

Comment: @Xerif la versión es la 5.6.36. He hecho una prueba pasando un solo valor del formulario y en el inspector se envia, pero no lo recoge, por lo que no creo que sea limitación del tamaño de la petición. Seguiré mirando

Comment: En el inspector, en network, parandote en el post request podés ver los parámetros enviados. Si los parámetros se envían, entonces fijate si php no está tirando ningún error.

Comment: Que el post va vacío supongo que implica que si haces un var_dump($_REQUEST) en el achivo donde lo recibes no hay nada?

Comment: @Carmen var_dump($_POST[]) me devuelve NULL

Comment: Si no lo tienes activado añade error_reporting y printa todos los errores para ver si da alguna pista de por dónde contuinuar, alguna función obsoleta o algo parecido

Comment: Puedes revisar también el log de apache... Revida si tu hosting tiene uno...

Comment: El log de apache lo único que me da es esto: PHP Notice:  Undefined index:$check y sucesivamente cada vez que uso $check en el array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución: Usar doble comillas al recoger en el post:

```
$r5Le = $_POST["r5LE_$check"];
```

y en el resto de valores. Después también en nuevo hosting han cambiado el SQL Mode a STRICT, cuando en el anterior estaba vacío: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/mysql-error-incorrect-integer-value-for-column-name-at-row-1

Con lo que daba error al intentar poner un valor de tipo diferente al de por defecto (NULL)